# Is this an example of a 'Static Bean'?

Tags: java, spring

```
public class SomeClass {

    private static final int num = 432;

    @Bean
    public int getNum(){
        return num;
    }

}
```

or would the method signature need to actually have the static keyword ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about what you mean about a static Bean, Beans are instances in runtime.

If you mean Singleton, meaning that the bean would be created on application start and destroyed in application end.

Then by default, every Bean is @Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.SINGLETON), if you want a bean to be created every new usage of it, you can define it as @Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE)

Take a look at the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of a static bean would be different. As an example, take a look at the [EventPublisherHolder](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/blob/c68c5a6f5b9a47eadd19baba257813cfc3959fd0/hawkbit-repository/hawkbit-repository-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/hawkbit/repository/model/helper/EventPublisherHolder.java) class from Eclipse Hawkbit:

```
public final class EventPublisherHolder {

    private static final EventPublisherHolder SINGLETON = new EventPublisherHolder();

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public static EventPublisherHolder getInstance() {
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    public ApplicationEventPublisher getEventPublisher() {
        return eventPublisher;
    }
    ...
}
```

The way the `ApplicationEventPublisher` is injected into the `EventPublisherHolder` is through Spring magic

```
@Bean
EventPublisherHolder eventBusHolder() {
    return EventPublisherHolder.getInstance();
}
```

The `EventPublisherHolder` class makes it easier to get the `ApplicationEventPublisher` statically.
As an example, take a look at the way this class is intended to be used:
From [JpaAction](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/blob/9cb5d313968d7f334a27c337ec6e98cabadf92ba/hawkbit-repository/hawkbit-repository-jpa/src/main/java/org/eclipse/hawkbit/repository/jpa/model/JpaAction.java#L237) class:

```java
@Override
public void fireCreateEvent(final DescriptorEvent descriptorEvent) {
     EventPublisherHolder.getInstance().getEventPublisher().publishEvent(new ActionCreatedEvent(...));
}
```

In this sense, you can consider the `EventPublisherHolder` bean to be a static bean.